# Adding multiple signals to User model creates record in forst table but not the second

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using the standard django.contrib.auth.models User model and have extended it to create a Profile model with a one to one relationship with User to hold the profile picture. The signal for this is working fine. I since added another model, Roles, which needs a regular foreign key to User as a user can have multiple roles. The latter gives consistent errors no matter how I try to configure it including  giving the fields different related_name in case it was confused which was which as well as having the Role model with a relationship to Profile rather than User but no matter how I seem to tackle it, I can't get the signal to work.

relevant models.py file code is as follows:

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Role(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.IntegerField('Roles',choices=Roles.choices, default=0)
   ...
```

signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from core.models import Profile, Role

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        Role.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
    instance.role.save()
```

The debug error I am getting is as follows:

```
AttributeError at /login/
'User' object has no attribute 'role'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'role'
Exception Location: C:\project\path\core\signals.py in save_profile, line 15
```

I expect it's something to do with setting up a separate signal rather than having them in the same def but haven't been able to crack it after trying numerous ways. Likely just a silly thing I'm missing and will be grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks for taking a look.

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user have not `role` but `roles`, is the default related name in foreignkey
you can change this by `foreignkey(... , related_name="your_name")`

so you can't do this for 2 reason

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
    instance.role.save()
```

instance not have `role` but `roles`

`instance.roles` is not object but a queryset/list of role models

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I've updated to roles instance.roles but now I get the error: AttributeError at /login/
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'. A bit of reading suggests that's related to the type of key and I expect what you mentioned about a queryset/list, but I'm not sure what to do to fix that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Playing around with your query/list comment, I changed the code to 'instance.user_role.first().save()' and changed the related_name to 'user_role'; this works but feels pretty clunky. It is only ever required to automate the initial creation of a role so will be fine, just wonder if there's a more elegant solution? Happy to be just able to sign-in again without unpicking the whole lot :-)

Comment: why you need to save profile and role when you save user ? saving profil and role witout change on profil and role is useless, explaine more about it

Comment: They are models for different things. Profile only ever is one to one with User. However, there are multiple Roles possible for a user. Whilst most only have one role, some have two so it must be a foreign key with 1 to many relationship between User and Role. There are several other fields in the Roles model to handle these requirements not covered in the standard User models and whilst I am using group and site and other standard user admin functionality; I needed Roles to extend these with a 1 to many relationship.